# unable to install node 8 dependencies on ubuntu 16.4

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm unable to install my project (that works very well under node 6). This is due to a dependency of node 8, that in addition to be deprecated also attempts to write somewhere where it doesn't have permissions.

```
ubuntu@ip-xxxxxxx:~/share_place/bin$ sudo npm i
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.4.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated jade@0.26.3: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated to-iso-string@0.0.2: to-iso-string has been deprecated, use @segment/to-iso-string instead.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b v0.5.5 git://github.com/bookchin/node-ntp-client.git /home/ubuntu/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-cd074428
npm ERR! /home/ubuntu/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-cd074428/.git: Permission denied
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2017-06-15T13_45_37_010Z-debug.log
ubuntu@ip-xxxxx:~/share_place/bin$ node -v
v8.1.2
```

It's very frustrating for us, since we're developing under windows and mac without issues, but now we're stuck at the preproduction.

Any help would be very welcome, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `npm` is running as root (because of `sudo`), it will drop root privileges right before executing external scripts/programs (like `git`). [By default](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#user) it will setuid to `nobody`.

This causes permission issues because `nobody` is most likely not allowed to write to the directory `/home/ubuntu/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-cd074428/` (hence the *"Permission denied"* error).

The best solution is to not use `sudo` at all. In your case, installing only local dependencies, it makes even less sense than the usual situation, where `sudo` is used to install something globally (`-g`).

Perhaps you may have to clean up the permissions in `/home/ubuntu/.npm/` too, if some files/directories in there now belong to `root`:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /home/ubuntu/.npm
```